# Ajax-Tooltips Links

Tags: jquery, ajax

I´ve a problem with the ajax tooltips qtip2.

I´m using this script (http://jsfiddle.net/craga89/L6yq3/):

```
// Create the tooltips only when document ready
$(document).ready(function()
{
 // MAKE SURE YOUR SELECTOR MATCHES SOMETHING IN YOUR HTML!!!
 $('a').each(function() {
     $(this).qtip({
        content: {
            text: 'Loading...',
            ajax: {
                url: 'http://qtip2.com/demos/data/owl',
                loading: false
            }
        },
        position: {
            viewport: $(window)
        },
        style: 'qtip-wiki'
     });
 });
});
```

And here the link for the tooltip:

```
 <a href='http://qtip2.com/demos/data/snowyowl'>Snowy Owl</a>
```

The problem is, that every link on the content page, where i´m using this script, tries to load a tooltip. Even if i hover over the menu items (which are links, of course) it tries to load the ajax tooltips. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is too generic, `$('a')` will select all anchor tags and setup tooltips for them. Instead just add/use an attribute to sepcify which anchor you need tooltip for. say for the anchors that needs to show a tooltip add a `rel="tooltip"` attribute and set up tooltips only for those ones.

ex:

```
<a rel="tooltip" href='http://qtip2.com/demos/data/snowyowl'>Show tooltip</a>
```

and you can just write it as (You don't need to use each)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    // MAKE SURE YOUR SELECTOR MATCHES SOMETHING IN YOUR HTML!!!
    $('a[rel="tooltip"]').qtip({
        content: {
            text: 'Loading...',
            ajax: {
                url: 'http://qtip2.com/demos/data/owl',
                loading: false
            }
        },
        position: {
            viewport: $(window)
        },
        style: 'qtip-wiki'
    });

});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hD6LX/)**